# How to resolve a stack trace in visual studio 2008

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, exception, stack-trace, nullreferenceexception

I'm developing an **ASP.NET** website in **Visual Studio 2008**. The thing is that I changed a line in the code. This change threw an exception (`NullReferenceException`) at runtime. After I changed the line back it still throws the same exception. I want to follow the stack trace to look into the error and solve it.  Can you guys give some tips?  Thanks.

EDIT:
I'm developing a Web Map Application with **ArcGIS Server 9.3.1**, Here's the stack trace:

> [NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.]
>          ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.DataSourceManager.AddDataSourceInstance(String type, String name, String identity, String definition) +666
>          ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.MapResourceItem.CreateResource() +404
>          ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.GISResourceManager2.initResourceItems() +170
>          ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls.GISResourceManager2.OnInit(EventArgs e) +149
>          System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +333
>          System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
>          System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) +210
>          System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +378

Comment: I would help, but I can't guess your stack trace.

Comment: Thanks Frederic, I edited the question with the stack trace.

Comment: Man, you're failing at DataSourceManager.AddDataSourceInstance() +666. What an evil stack trace :]

Comment: I did notice that, but I don't know how to fix it, I've created a new solution with the basic components only, and still get the same error.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem using a `Debug` build of your new solution. File names and line numbers are usually more useful than address offsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Maybe assembly was not reloaded if it thows the same exception while code is changed back?
- could be about data or configuration
- if you do not have a source code, you can not follow the stack trace in debug

Comment: How can I force the assembly to reload?

Comment: Recycle the application pool in IIS. Or kill `w3wp.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

You should also do a `Clean Solution` (from the `Build` menu).  This will remove any compilations that it is caching for the ASP.Net page.

Comment: those are not line numbers. They're offsets from the start of the function's machine code. Questioner is using a release build.

Comment: Removed that section of my answer.  Thank you.